# Performing Segue in didReceive response: UNNotificationResponse

Tags: swift, push-notification

I'm new to Swift and I'm trying to integrate it with firebase push notification.
The push notification itself is working just fine but I'm having a hard time opening specific view when touching the notification.

First I tried initializing the root view controller by instantaiteViewController method but it didn't work
So I Secondly tried if I can perform segue from the initial view controller when the user taps on the notification.

The second solution is what I want to achieve currently.
And calling the perform segue method from the "didReceive response: UNNotificationResponse," from UNUserNotificationCenterDelegate

It seems to be performing the segue. checking by printing a string in the `ViewDidLoad()` and `ViewWillApear` of the destination ViewController.

Except it isn't showing the screen of it.
The screen still shows me the initial view controller even after firing the destination view controller ViewDidload

Is this about the life cycle or is it simply not able to do this?

```
func userNotificationCenter(_ center: UNUserNotificationCenter,
                          didReceive response: UNNotificationResponse,
                          withCompletionHandler completionHandler: @escaping () -> Void) {
    let userInfo = response.notification.request.content.userInfo
    if let messageID = userInfo[gcmMessageIDKey] {
        print("Message ID: \(messageID)")
    }

    let notification = response.notification
    if notification.request.trigger is UNPushNotificationTrigger{
        print("didRecieve Push Notification")
    }else{
        print("did Recieve Local Notification")
    }
    print("notification.requset.identifier: \(notification.request.identifier)")

    self.window = UIWindow(frame: UIScreen.main.bounds)
    let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name:"Main",bundle: nil)
    print(storyboard)
    if let userShowCase = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier:"userShowCase") as? userShowCaseViewController {
        print(storyboard)

        self.window?.rootViewController = userShowCase
        self.window?.makeKeyAndVisible()
        userShowCase.performSegue(withIdentifier: "showCase2Login", sender: userShowCase)

    }

    completionHandler()
}
```

Comment: Did you ever end up figuring this out? Been stuck on it as well.